# Huge memory use from small powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have this script to trap the IP's on a network to compare to historic packet captures as part of a larger problem solving exercise.

```
function qp($comp)
    {
    $p = ping $comp -n 1 -w 2 -4
    IF($? -eq $true){$out = $p[1].split("[")[1].split("]")[0]}
    else{$out = $False}
    return $out
    }

$comps = Get-Content C:\PacketCapture\comps.txt

DO
    {
    foreach($comp in $comps)
        {
        ECHO "$(qp $comp);$comp" >>"C:\PacketCapture\IP_$(Get-date -format HHmm-ddMMyy).txt"
        }
    Start-sleep 3600
    }
until($null -eq "WANG")
```

I set this off initially a fortnight ago, at the middle of last week the terminal it was running on was grinding to a halt as the memory use for the power shell process was nearly at 2GB.

I stopped and restarted it and again we were at 1.2GB RAM use this morning.

Whilst not particularly critical, I've modified this to run once then stop/start itself, I'm interested to know which element is causing the memory leak and how I would identify that in the future.

Comment: I could see it being worse but have you tried using `Test-Connnection -Quiet`? It would remove the need for string manipulation although that should finish rather quickly. Also what PowerShell version are you running this with.

Comment: First, how large is `comps.txt`? Second, why even use ping.exe when there's [Test-Connection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849808.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) cmdlet? Finally, your do..until is funny but `while ($true) { ... }` is more common.

Comment: You could also try [PingInfoView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multiple_ping_tool.html) (example: `PingInfoView.exe /loadfile C:\PacketCapture\comps.txt /scomma C:\PacketCapture\oufile.csv`).

Comment: I agree with the others about using `Test-Connection`. That said, what if you sprinkled in a `[GC]::Collect()`, maybe in the look after the `Start-Sleep`? Just curious if that helps.

Comment: Try VMMap from sysinternals. It allows you to view the memory usage pattern of a process over time. When at 1.2GB ram, you could take a memory dump using procdump (or procexp or taskmanager -> right click -> create dumpfile) and analyze it with WinDbg.

Comment: fwiw - I didn't notice any memory drain/leak when running this on my computer with the Start-Sleep removed.

Comment: @Matt Errm - you are absolutely correct about test-connection. I use a version of that ping function as a much faster replacement for test connection, it lives in my profile and frankly I'd forgotten that there was a native alternative.

Comment: @AlexanderObersht Comps.txt is tiny, it generates live depending on who's logged on to what machine but the maximum size is only ever going to be 45 entries. See my reply to @Matt for the my lack of reasoning behind not using test-connection... out of interest, would there be a reason, beyond following good code practice, to using `while($true)` rather than my own hackery? Performance?

Comment: @briantist `[GC]::Collect()` is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. New to me but gives me a place to start.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Thanks, I'm going to run this up on a test VM (not at my clients productions site) and try these suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try invoking garbage collection manually. I think the `do`/`until` loop is a good place for it:

```
DO
    {
    foreach($comp in $comps)
        {
        ECHO "$(qp $comp);$comp" >>"C:\PacketCapture\IP_$(Get-date -format HHmm-ddMMyy).txt"
        }
    Start-sleep 3600
    [GC]::Collect()
    }
until($null -eq "WANG")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try introducing garbage collection into your code with `[System.GC]::Collect()`

Source : https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/freeing-up-memory-in-powershell-using-garbage-collector

Comment: You should actually include the code from the link... its one line. This is a poor answer without it.

Comment: I think it is a fantastic answer, I think your comment is a poor comment.

Comment: It is the right answer but what happens when the link dies? This is a link-only answer right now which is discouraged at SO. My comment is not poor. It is an attempt at constructive criticism.

Comment: it is not a link only answer, my text precedes it

the link ensures attribution - and if it dies my text is sufficient to find an alternate solution

Comment: But users wouldn't have to bother finding anything if you wrote the 15 characters in the answer and kept the link for context is my point.

Comment: Jimbo thanks for the answer, Matt is technically correct. Stack Overflow prefer you include the crux of your answer here and not just via a link. However @Matt, Stack Overflow is collaborative, feel free to edit Jimbo's answer to include the pertinent details.

Comment: @Patrick I am aware of that yes. I was taking the teach a man to fish approach.

Comment: @Matt I first read that as teach a man to fist, I wondered what I'd got myself into. I hadn't seen your scores when I commented and also thought it best to educate, Its a never ending cycle.